# How to render Tweet buttons using REST API in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, ember.js, requirejs

I am using emberjs-requirejs as the basis for a project and would like to be able to include Tweet buttons within the templates that are rendered by javascript using the twitter 1.1 rest api.

There are several examples for using @anywhere, but that is deprecated and no longer works. I do not wish to include the javascript manually on the page, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to using the following code in my require.js config to load Twitter's widgets.js.

```
define({
  app_name: "MyExampleApp",

  shim : {
    'ember.min' : {
      deps: ['handlebars.dev', 'jquery2'],
      exports: 'Ember'
    },
    'emberFacebook':{
      deps:['ember.min']
    },
    'App':{
    deps:['ember.min']
    }
    'jquery.ui': ['jquery2']
    },

    paths : {
        'App': 'app/main',
        'models': 'app/models',
        'views': 'app/views',
        'controllers': 'app/controllers',
                'templates': 'app/templates',
        'routes': 'app/routes',

        /*libs*/
        'jquery2': 'libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min',
        'twitter': '//platform.twitter.com/widgets',
        'handlebars.dev': 'libs/handlebars/1.3.0/handlebars.dev',
        'ember.min': 'libs/ember/1.3.1/ember.prod.min',
        'emberFacebook': 'libs/ember-facebook',

        /*requirejs-plugins*/
        'text': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/text',
        'hbs': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/hbs',
        'domReady': 'libs/requirejs-plugins/domReady'
    },

    /*hbs plugin options*/
    hbs: {
        disableI18n: true,
        templateExtension: "html"
    }
});
```

Placing button code on the webpage is enough, once widgets.js is loaded the buttons are then activated.